# how can i console.log how the #form values will be sent?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

i know we can manally log any input value by its selector

```
console.log('inputName='+$('#inputId').val()+'....)
```

But is there -simpler- a way to log all input values? if it's posible to do it when any input changes

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use [`serialize`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) to serialize the form elements to a string for logging. It follows the same rules for including or not including elements as normal form submission. The only caveat is that the content of `input type="file"` fields isn't serialized, for perhaps obvious reasons.

To fire it when any of the inputs changes:

```
$("form :input").change(function() {
    console.log($(this).closest('form').serialize());
});
```

[Live demo](http://jsbin.com/ecujat/2) using the form shown in the documentation

Comment: nice! how can i get that fired on any input (select or text) changes?

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet: I've updated the answer to show how. I just used the `change` event, which may not fire early enough for you on text inputs. If so, just throw some keyboard events on as well. That won't be comprehensive (wouldn't detect right-click and then choosing Paste from the menu), but I take it this is for debugging, so it's probably good enough.

Answer (score 1):

You may get in form of query string using `$("form").serialize()`.

Answer (score 1):

This would log the form every time anything changes:

```
$("form :input").change(function(){
   console.log($("form").serialize());
});
```

**Edit:**

Removed my focusout suggestion, as I realized that change is actually only fired when the element looses focus.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder good catch, updated my answer to get select, and textarea as well.

Answer (score 1):

I made this little component:

```
$("form :input").change(function() {  
    var fields = $(this).closest('form').serialize();
    serialize_to_console( fields );
 });


/*
  SERIALIZE TO CONSOLE
  Transforms string to array and show each param in console if not empty */
var serialize_to_console = function( serialized ) { 

    var splited_serialized = serialized.split('&');

    $.each( splited_serialized, function(index, key) { 

        var input = key.substr(0, key.indexOf('=')); 
        var value = key.substr( key.indexOf('=') + 1 ); 

        if( value !== '' )
        console.log( '[' + input + '] = \'' + value + '\'' );
    });

}
```

Enjoy!